# Highlight Border Color Using Jquery Animate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I want to **highlight** the borders of a **textfield** using **animate** function, when click on **Add Animation Link**.

Like this:

[image]

**Js Fiddle Here:** http://jsfiddle.net/N9um8/20/

**HTML :**

```
<div>   
     <p>
         <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search for people...." class="field_style">
     </p>            
     <p> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_animation">Add Animation</a> </p>    
</div>

    <p class="styling"> I want it like this when click on Add Animation :</p>    

<div>   
     <p>
         <input type="text" name="test_search" id="test_search" placeholder="Search for people...." class="test_field_style">
     </p>     
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.field_style { width:400px; }

.styling { color:red; }

.test_field_style {
     border-color: #6EA2DE; 
     box-shadow: 0 0 10px #6EA2DE;
     width:400px;  
}
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(".add_animation").click(function (){

    $("#search").focus().animate({ "background-color": "#B6DADA" }, 800, "linear");     

});
```

Comment: You can't really animate colors or box shadow with jQuery, at least not without using the step method and jQuery UI etc. but you could just do what everyone else is doing, use CSS3 -> http://jsfiddle.net/N9um8/21/

Comment: Alright its working fine but it should remove the class when this textfield lost focus

Comment: So just add that -> http://jsfiddle.net/N9um8/30/

Comment: @adeneo Thats working fine, and whats with the background color ?

Comment: If you wan't to add a background color, just add it to the class -> http://jsfiddle.net/N9um8/35/

Answer (score 1):

`backgroundColor` is not an animatable property with jQuery animate by default.  In general, it cannot animate colors.  You will have a much better time using simple CSS transitions although they are not as widely supported (IE9- will not).

```
.field_style {
    width:400px;
    transition: box-shadow .8s linear;
    outline: 0;
}
.field_style:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #6EA2DE;
    border-color: #6EA2DE;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N9um8/31/

.8s is a bit long for the animation by the way.

Comment: Cant see Jquery Code in your fiddle

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of different options. The best performance-wise would definitely be CSS:

The JS:

```
$(".add_animation").click(function (){

    $("#search").focus(function() {
        $(this).css({backgroundColor: '#B6DADA'});
    }).blur(function() {
        $(this).css({backgroundColor: '#fff'});
    }).focus();

});
```

The CSS:

```
#search {
    -webkit-transition: .8s background linear;
    -moz-transition: .8s background linear;
    -ms-transition: .8s background linear;
    -o-transition: .8s background linear;
    transition: .8s background linear;
}
```

[The fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N9um8/34/)

Another way is using a jQuery plugin or something (my favorite is called [jquery color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color)) to animate your colors.

```
$(".add_animation").click(function (){

    $("#search").focus(function() {
        $(this).animate({backgroundColor: '#B6DADA'}, 800, 'linear');
    }).blur(function() {
        $(this).animate({backgroundColor: '#fff'}, 800, 'linear');
    }).focus();

});
```

[The fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N9um8/33/)

Comment: Borders are still not highlighted

Comment: Just add `borderColor: '#ccc'` or whatever color you want into your js.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this plugin : http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/ and append :

```
<script src="http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/jquery.animate-colors-min.js"></script>
```

An example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/N9um8/20/